# Set a relationship with Core Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, entity-relationship

I have two entities that are connected through a one-to-many relationship, let's say ***CategoryEntity*** and ***ItemEntity***. The relationship is optional for CategoryEntity (there can be categories without items), but required for every ItemEntity. At the app's loading, the Categories already exist in the store, and I want to import ItemEntities and connect them to the appropriate CategoryEntity.

Obviously executing a FetchRequest for each ItemEntity to find the matching category wouldn't be a good solution because there will be about 4000-6000 Items each time..

So, is there something more efficient I could do?

Comment: Fetches are used to retrieve managed objects (MOs). Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to assign a CategoryEntity MO instance to an ItemEntity MO instance? Or are you asking how to fetch a list of ItemEntity MOs that do not have a CategoryEntity assignment, and assign a specific CategoryEntity MO to them?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I wasn't very clear in my question. I'm asking how to assign a CategoryEntity MO instance to newly created ItemEntity MO instances. Every ItemEntity MO though should be assigned to the appropriate CategoryEntity MO.

I think I did it by using a Dictionary for faster reference of the categories, but any better architecture is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you have correctly setup your Core Data model, then you have a to-many relationship from the Category entity to the Item entity, and an inverse to-one relationship from Item to Category. Also, you have a "cascade" delete rule for the to-many relationship and a "nullify" delete rule for the to-one relationship.

Assuming this, each time you insert an Item object, setting its Category relationship automatically inserts the Item into the corresponding Category. Deleting an Item automatically removes it from the corresponding Category.

On the Category side, removing a Category automatically removes all of the corresponding Item objects.

Therefore, when you fetch Items, you have already fetched for each Item object its corresponding Category object. You do not need do anything else. Note that, by default, you are not actually retrieving the Category object during the fetch: instead a fault is fired the first time you try to access the object and the object is retrieved at that time. This provides better performances if you do not plan to use immediately the Category object stored within the Item object just fetched. If you plan to use the Category object almost every time you fetch an Item, then you must use the NSFetchRequest methods

```
- (void)setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:(BOOL)yesNo
- (void)setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:(NSArray *)keys
```

to tell Core Data that you do now want faults and that you ask for prefetching your Category  relationship.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'import' item entities, what do you mean? Are these in another Core Data store, defined in another format in a file somewhere, retrieved over the network?

One approach would be to fetch all the categories in one go and add them to an NSDictionary acting as a cache and keyed by some identifying value that allows you to perform a quick lookup. For each item entity that you instantiate during import (whatever that means), retrieve its category ID and then retrieve the Category MO from the cache. Set the relationship and then save. Even better, batch up a number of insertions and save every 10, 100 or 1000 to reduce IO overhead.